# Passing key to compare value in loop with parameter function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pass in function array (list), keyField, and value to compare

I tried for this following code :

```
let _ = require('lodash')

filterListBy(list, keyField,value) {
  return _.filter(list, function (data) {
      return data.keyField.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()
    })
  }

let arr=[{
"name":"ABC",
"subject":"Java"
},{
"name":"XYZ",
"subject":"Java"
},{
"name":"PQR",
"subject":"Javascript"
}]

console.log(filterListBy(arr,'subject','java'))
```

But getting error :

```
return data.keyField.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
```

I want to pass different array at many time and pass different keyField that's why i am trying this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function filterListBy(list, keyField,value) {
  return _.filter(list, function (data) {
      return data[keyField].toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()
    })
  }
```

`[]` can be used to access an object by an expression key (as opposed to an identifier).

Answer (score 0):

Each object in arr variable  that you declare has two keys, name and subject **{'name':'', 'subject':''}**. But in your code you use **data.keyField.toUpperCase()**, and this is wrong. Because javascript understand this like **{'keyField': ''}**, which is not defined. You should use **data[keyField]** instead, and this means data.subject in your case.